# What does $p\frac{\Bbb d^2v}{\Bbb dp^2} + 2(l+1-p)\frac{\Bbb dv}{\Bbb dp}+\big(k-2(l+1)\big)v = 0$ when $x=2p$ (variable change of an ODE)?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, problem-solving, change-of-variable

I’m reading a lecture in which this ODE:
$$p\frac{\Bbb d^2v}{\Bbb dp^2} + 2(l+1-p)\frac{\Bbb dv}{\Bbb dp}+\big(k-2(l+1)\big)v = 0$$
is rearranged by the identity $x = 2p$ into this:
$$x\frac{\Bbb d^2v}{\Bbb dx^2}+\big(2(l+1)-x\big)\frac{\Bbb dv}{\Bbb dx}+\left(\frac{1}{2}k-(l+1)\right)v = 0.$$

To be clear, $v$ is initially a function of $p$ (I’m guessing it would then become a function of $\frac{1}{2}x$ but I’m unsure). Also, $l$ and $k$ are variables.

I understand how the coefficient of $\frac{\Bbb dv}{\Bbb dx}$ is achieved as $2p$ is just substituted for $x$. However the coefficient of $v$ is suddenly halved and the coefficient of $\frac{\Bbb d^2v}{\Bbb dx^2}$ suddenly doubled (or so it appears to me) and I can’t work out why.

Comment: Replace $p$ with $\frac{x}{2}$, $\frac{dv}{dp}$ with $\frac{dv}{dx}\frac{dx}{dp}=2\frac{dv}{dx}$, and $\frac{d^2v}{dp^2}$ with $4\frac{d^2v}{dx^2}$ in the original ODE.

Comment: Thanks, completely forgot the chain rule! ‍♂️ If you’d like to submit that as an answer I’ll accept it @Gonçalo